# citep not working with apacite

Tags: citing, apa-style, apacite

I am unable to make use of the `\citep{}` function on LaTeX, using Texmaker. `\cite{}` works just fine, however.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lmodern,microtype}
%\usepackage{titlesec,titling}
\usepackage{enumitem,booktabs}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont,mathrsfs,ushort}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}


\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]
\newcommand*{\myplus}{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\pmb{+}}}}


\chapterfont{\color{blue}}  % sets 
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}  % sets colour of sections
\subsectionfont{\color{red}}  % sets colour of sections


\begin{document}

\chapter{citations}

\begin{enumerate}
  \Citation 1 \cite{a1}.
  \Citation2 \citep{a2}.
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References}


\end{document}
```

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try with  `biblatex-apa`  and `\parencite`?

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate. Is biblatex-apa the bibliography style?

Comment: When you use `biblatex`, it defines an `apa` style.

Comment: I tried it with biblatex-apa, and it does not work.

Comment: Yes, but biblatex is easier to customise. Could you post a small complete code, and explain what's not working and what you're trying to obtain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apacite` package knows three modes of operation with respect to citation commands.

1. Its default behaviour is that of the option `apaciteclassic`, which defines a set of citation commands useful for APA style. The main commands are `\cite`, `\citeA` and `\citeNP`.
2. The package option `natbibapa` loads `natbib` and thus enables use of `natbib`'s citation commands `\citet`, `\citep` etc.
3. The option `nocitation` defines no new citation commands and is intended to be used by users who want to define their own commands or who want to try to use the `apacite` package with a third-party citation package.

See p. 7 of [the `apacite` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf).

In your MWE you load `apacite` without options as `\usepackage{apacite}` and hence you get the default behaviour of `apaciteclassic`. That means that `natbib`'s `\citet` and `\citep` are not available, but you can use `\cite`, `\citeA` and `\citeNP`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}

\citeA{appleby}

\citeNP{appleby}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Appleby, 1980)//Appleby (1980)//Appleby, 1980]

If you want to be able to use `\citep` and `\citet`, you need to load the package with the `natbibapa` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{appleby}

\citep{appleby}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby (1980)//(Appleby, 1980)]

---

If you are willing to switch to `biblatex`, you can use `biblatex-apa` and make use of `biblatex`'s set of citation commands as suggested by [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482253/citep-not-working-with-apacite#comment1218956_482253).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}

\parencite{appleby}

\textcite{appleby}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that this requires Biber instead of BibTeX, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).